# Batch .txt reader

Tags: batch-file, auto-update, chatroom

So, basically I want a Batch file to read a .txt. The problem is that the Batch file needs to update everytime a new line gets written to the .txt

```
@echo off
set "pc=%1"
FOR /F "delims=:" %%A IN ('findstr /N .* "%pc%"') DO set "zeilen=%%A" 
type %pc%
set /A zeilen1=%zeilen%
:loop
if not %zeilen% == %zeilen1% (
set "line="
set zeilen2=%zeilen% - 1
for /f %%a in ('more/e +%zeilen2% ^< %pc%') do (
   if not defined line set "line=%%a"
)
 echo %line%   
 set /A zeilen+=1
)
FOR /F "delims=:" %%A IN ('findstr /N .* "%pc%"') DO set "zeilen1=%%A
goto loop
```

I also can't use the type command (line 9-13) because I don't want to refresh the whole .txt only the last line.

sry for my poor english

Thanks

To start the Batch you need to do something like this `call batch.cmd txtname.txt`

Comment: So you're basically trying to do the batch version of `tail -f`?

Comment: You can get the `TAIL` command from the [Windows 2003 Resource Kit](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=17657)

Comment: @ErrorsOnly, please see my comments below the answer you accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't wish to use third party options and wish to keep it pure batch, it is very possible. From your question, it sounds like you wish to read the last line of a text file and have it update that text each time the text file is edited. Further more, this batch file much be `call`'ed to when it needs to be used.

To do this, we can compare the date it was last modified using `forfiles` in an `for loop`. The reason for this is that if we use the file properties EX: `ECHO Last-Modified Date : %%~ta` we will not get the properties down to seconds. Thus the file will only compare down to the minutes.

Now that we can grab the last modified properties we can use an `IF` statement to look for when the file get a new time stamp. From there we can use a modified script that reads only the last line of a text file (Configurable by `set /a LINES=LINES+1` LINES+1 - Infin) made by [@Patrick Cuff](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7903/patrick-cuff)

To call this batch file you will want to use `call ReadFile.bat txtname.txt`

- **Call** - Command
- **ReadFile.bat** - Name of batch script
- **txtname.txt** - Name of textfile to read

Bellow is the full script.

**ReadFile.bat**

```
@ECHO OFF
@GOTO READ

:LOOP
Rem | Look for changes
FOR /f %%a in ('forfiles /M %1 /C "cmd /c echo @fdate-@ftime"') DO (set FileTimeCurrent=%%a)

IF "%FileTimeLoad%"=="%FileTimeCurrent%" (goto LOOP) else (goto READ)

:READ
cls

Rem | Get current date
FOR /f %%a in ('forfiles /M %1 /C "cmd /c echo @fdate-@ftime"') DO (set FileTimeLoad=%%a)

Rem | Get the number of lines in the file
set LINES=0
for /f "delims==" %%I in (%1) do (
    set /a LINES=LINES+1
)

Rem | Print the last line
set /a LINES=LINES-1
more +%LINES% < %1

goto LOOP
```

For help on any of the commands do the following:

- call /?
- set /?
- for /?
- if /?
- So on.

Comment: There are a few flaws with this code both dealing with calculating the amount of lines and outputting the newly updated lines. 1) Per the help file for the `FOR /F` command, blank lines are skipped.  So the calculation of how many lines there are in the file could be incorrect.  You should consider using the `FIND` command with the `/C` option instead. 2) If multiple lines are written to the file before you see that the file time changed it will only print the last line.  It will not see that two, three or multiple lines have been written to the file. It has the potential to miss new lines.

Comment: And of course as the file grows larger and larger the script will get slower and slower because it has to read the entire file to get the number of lines and then skip all of them except for the last one.

Answer (score 2):

A basic tail command can be written like so.  Credit to @dbenham for his initial solution on [DosTips.com](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=7078)

```
@echo off
call :Loop <"tailme.txt"

exit

:Loop
set "line="
set /p "line="
if defined line (
  echo %line%
) else (
  pathping -q 1 -p 300 localhost >nul
)
goto :loop
```